# terminal/datatype/parser rules in xtext

Tags: antlr, xtext

I'm using xtext 2.4. 
What I want to do is a SQL-like syntax.
The things confuse me are I'm not sure which things should be treated as terminal/datatype/parser rules. So far my grammar related to `MyTerm` is:

```
Model:
    (terms += MyTerm ';')*
;

MyTerm:
    constant=MyConstant | variable?='?'| collection_literal=CollectionLiteral 
;

MyConstant
    : string=STRING 
    | number=MyNumber
    | date=MYDATE 
    | uuid=UUID 
    | boolean=MYBOOLEAN
    | hex=BLOB
;

MyNumber:
    int=SIGNINT | float=SIGNFLOAT
;


SIGNINT returns ecore::EInt:
    '-'? INT
;


SIGNFLOAT returns ecore::EFloat:
    '-'? INT '.' INT;
;

CollectionLiteral:
    => MapLiteral | SetLiteral | ListLiteral
;

MapLiteral:
    '{' {MapLiteral} (entries+=MapEntry (',' entries+=MapEntry)* )? '}'
;

MapEntry:
    key=MyTerm ':' value=MyTerm
;

SetLiteral:
    '{' {SetLiteral} (values+=MyTerm (',' values+=MyTerm)* )+ '}'
;

ListLiteral:
    '[' {ListLiteral} ( values+=MyTerm (',' values+=MyTerm)* )? ']'
;

terminal MYDATE:
  '0'..'9' '0'..'9' '0'..'9' '0'..'9' '-'
  '0'..'9' '0'..'9' '-'
  '0'..'9' '0'..'9'
;

terminal HEX:
    'a'..'h'|'A'..'H'|'0'..'9'
;   

terminal UUID:
    HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX '-'
    HEX HEX HEX HEX '-'
    HEX HEX HEX HEX '-'
    HEX HEX HEX HEX '-'
    HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX HEX
;

terminal BLOB:
    '0' ('x'|'X') HEX+
;

terminal MYBOOLEAN returns ecore::EBoolean:
    'true' | 'false' | 'TRUE' | 'FALSE'
;
```

Few questions:

- How to define integer with sign? If I define another terminal rule `terminal SIGNINT: '-'? '0'..'9'+;`, antlr will complain about INT becoming unreachable. Therefore I define it as a datatype rule `SIGNINT: '-'? INT;` Is this the correct way to do it?
- How to define float with sign? I did exactly the same as define integer with sign, `SIGNFLOAT: '-'? INT '.' INT;`, not sure if this is correct as well.
- How to define a date rule? I want to use a parser rule to store year/month/day info in fields, but define it as `MyDate: year=INT '-' month=INT '-' date=INT;` antlr will complain `Decision can match input such as "RULE_INT '-' RULE_INT '-' RULE_INT" using multiple alternatives: 2, 3
  As a result, alternative(s) 3 were disabled for that input`
- I also have some other rules like

the following

```
RelationCompare:
    name=ID compare=COMPARE term=MyTerm
;
```

but `a=4` won't be a valid `RelationCompare` because `a` and `4` will be treat as `HEX`s. I found this because if I change the relation to `j=44` then it works. In this [post](http://zarnekow.blogspot.com/2012/11/xtext-corner-6-data-types-terminals-why.html) it said terminal rule defined eariler will shadow those defined later. However, if I redefine `terminal ID` in my grammar, whether put it in front or after of `terminal HEX`, antlr will conplain `The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: RULE_HEX,RULE_MYBOOLEAN`. This problem happens in `k=0x00b` as well. `k=0xaab` is valid but `k=0x00b` is not.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Later I found the original antlr grammar for what I want to do therefore I simply translate the antlr grammar to xtext grammar. Here is how I defining those basic types:

```
terminal fragment A: 'a'|'A';  
   ... 
terminal fragment Z: 'z'|'Z';

terminal fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';
terminal fragment LETTER: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');
terminal fragment HEX: ('a'..'f'|'A'..'F'|'0'..'9'); 

terminal fragment EXPONENT: E ('+'|'-')? DIGIT+;
terminal INTEGER returns ecore::EInt: '-'? DIGIT+;
terminal FLOAT returns ecore::EFloat: INTEGER EXPONENT | INTEGER '.' DIGIT* EXPONENT?;

terminal BOOLEAN: T R U E | F A L S E;
```

The Date rule in original grammar is treated as a string.

About rules name (Rules: Antlr Grammar => xtext Grammar)

- parser rule: starting with lowercase => rules starting with uppercase (each will be a Java Class)
- terminal rule: starting with uppercase => using all uppercase with `terminal` prefix
- fragment terminal rule: `fragment` ID => `terminal fragment` ID

In antlr a list of arguments is defined like this:

```
functionArgs
  : '(' ')'
  | '(' t1=term ( ',' tn=term )* ')'
;
```

The corresponding xtext grammar is:

```
FunctionArgs
 : '(' ')'
 | '(' ts+=Term  (',' ts+=Term )* ')'
;
```

For those parser rules with an argument enclosed by `[` `]`

```
properties[PropertyDefinitions props]
  : property[props] (K_AND property[props])*
;
```

Most of the time they could be moved to the left hand side

```
Properties
  : props+=Property (K_AND props+=Property)*
;
```

Now it's working as expected.

Comment: Hi, if you use `terminal INTEGER returns ecore::EInt: '-'? DIGIT+;`, how did you deal with the minus calculation? Since it will treat `1-2` as TOKEN `1` and TOKEN `-2`.

Answer (score 3):

How do you define an integer with sign?

- Treat it as two separate tokens `'-'` and `INT`, and use a parser rule instead of a lexer rule.

How do you define a float with sign?

- Treat it as two separate tokens `'-'` and `FLOAT`, and use a parser rule instead of a lexer rule.

How do you define a date rule?

- Treat it as five separate tokens and use a parser rule instead of a lexer rule.

I don't know the answer to the last question since this is in Xtext as opposed to just ANTLR.