# Xtext grammar of negative numbers: terminal vs datatype rules

Tags: eclipse, grammar, xtext

What I would like to achive is an Xtext grammar which is able to distinguish between negative numerics of type `int` and `float`.

As I faced the same term problems as [eclipse community](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/202744/674007/#msg_674007), I followed their recommendation, to write both as **datatype rules**:

```
SignedInteger returns ecore::EIntegerObject:
  '-'? INT;

SignedFloat returns ecore::EFloatObject:
  '-'? INT* '.' INT+;
```

But the above will give me the following error (and finally i have the same problem by the leading minus sign):

```
Decision can match input such as "RULE_INT" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
```

To solve this I could write both as **terminal rules**, but then the grammar will conflict in:

```
The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens 
match the same input: RULE_INT
```

because both rules are hidden behinded the [Xtext common terminals](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.xtext.doc/help/CommonTerminals.html) rule `INT`.

It seem like the solution for one of the problems would force a conflic with the other one. Any recommendations how to solve this?

---

Besides another question refering ecore datatypes: What return type would you recommend, whats the difference between EInt and EIntegerObject? (Is the second the wrapper class of the primitive type?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [terminal/datatype/parser rules in xtext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089514/terminal-datatype-parser-rules-in-xtext)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089514/terminal-datatype-parser-rules-in-xtext - I guess, the accepted answer would work for you as well.

Comment: Ok, i adapted my grammar like so: `terminal INTEGER returns ecore::EInt : '-'? DIGIT+ ;` but even after I replaced all `INTs` by `INTEGER` I still get an `...prior tokens match the same input: RULE_INT` error which i don't understand. What does force those error? Can you give any more hints what to look for please.

Comment: Whats the sense of redefining `INT` as fragment `DIGIT`? For me it looks like the same to replace `DIGIT+` by `INT` in `INTEGER`Rule. But unfortunately that neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by [removing](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/489921/) the `with` common terminals statement. And copied  the rest (without the INT rule) i need into my own grammar. So there is no conflict any more.

But i guess that is not realy the root of the problem....
**If anyone can explain what's going on here I would be very thankful.**
(I hope that way does not bring later problems with it)